# Google Drive Api v3 sending automated queries

Tags: java, google-drive-api

When I use the `Google Drive API` to make a direct download using an API key, after more than one download using the link it doesn't work anymore and shows this message:

[image]

Comment: What is the language you are using to interact with the API? Are you using any type of _Live Server_ with it?

Comment: @YancyGodoy I'm use only url with api v3 to get direct link

Comment: How frequently are you executing that call? Is this automated or manual?

Comment: @YancyGodoy automated

Comment: Short answers are not useful, please modify your answer and provide more details as to how your set up is built, how is are requests executed, there's something locally that keeps on refreshing and sending automated requests that's why you are getting this error.